# Reasons for using empty link to call js instead of other html elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

In HTML development everywhere I see
ugly empty anchors to call JavaScript (I do it like this too):

```
<a href="#">Call some JavaScript</a>
<a href="javascript: void(0);">Call some JavaScript</a> 
<a href="javascript:;">Call some JavaScript</a>
```

I think empty links were used in past because of css :hover not working on other elements,
and for default cursor: pointer styling.

- Is this still considered best practice today?
- Are there any problems in using cleaner markup?

Like:

```
<span class="clickable">Call some javascipt</span>
```

Comment: Empty anchors are not OK, but a hash as a href is valid, and an anchor is after all the correct element for something that is supposed to lead to something else when clicked. That said, the second and third anchors in your question are considered bad practice. The first is OK if you use it with proper event handlers, not inline javascript.

Comment: @adeneo Could you elaborate why are second and third considered bad pratice as I often see this? And it doesn't append ugly hash to adress.

Comment: The hash is totally valid as a link to an element when an ID is added, and without an ID it simply scrolls to the top of the page and is still valid in all browsers ever made, so it's an excellent choice for anchors that should have javascript functionality added with external event handlers. For inline javascript, void(0) is probably better as it avoids issues when someone forgets to return false from the onclick function, but as we shouldn't really use javascript inline at all, that's not a valid point. Best practice is to not have any javascript in the HTML, only the first one does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasons

1. Semantically it is correct to use an anchor for a click, as it relates to an action and means for accessibility screen readers see it as an action.
2. It keeps the default user interaction in place of the link styling etc
3. Some mobiles wont play nicely with span and click binding, and you will find allot less cross device issues using an anchor.

I do agree that it is mark up bulk, but for accessibility its pretty important.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `second one` like,

```
<span class="clickable">Call some JavaScript</span>
```

For this, you have to add `css` for this `clickable class` like,

```
.clickable {
   cursor:pointer;/* you can use hand in place of pointer */
   color:blue;
}
.clickable:hover {
   color:red;/* you can add more properties on hover of span */
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rwRKL/)